# Send Image in Whatsapp without showing in Image editer of whatsapp?

Tags: java, android, image, whatsapp

I am making a demo app which functionality is that send image automatically without showing it in whatsapp image editor. How can I send the image directly my app to whatsapp?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84YmR.jpg)

[Video Demo](https://kapwi.ng/w/JqzZt_KJto)

On button click i am sending image but open below screen which i don't want and share image directly to my contact.

Here is demo Video to send image directly application to whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to bypass the video editor. You need to go through it.